# How to add input data to SQL value?

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

We want to create a medical information system. In this system, we have to buy medicines. When a user buys medicine, he/she has to enter barcode number and number of the buying medicine. We want to take number of medicines to be taken and add this value to SQL table. But we have an error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '10013''where Barcode='10013'' at line 1
```

[SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz7mD.png)

Here is my code:
**BuyMedicine.java**

...

```
BarcodeField = new JTextField();
    BarcodeField.setBounds(130, 26, 294, 21);
    contentPane.add(BarcodeField);
    BarcodeField.setColumns(10);

    NumberField = new JTextField();
    NumberField.setBounds(130, 86, 294, 21);
    contentPane.add(NumberField);
    NumberField.setColumns(100);

    JButton btnBuy = new JButton("Buy");
    btnBuy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root","");
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                String x = "Select Stock from medicinelist where Barcode='" + BarcodeField.getText()+"'";
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt2 = con.prepareStatement(x);
                preparedStmt2.execute();
                String sql = "Update medicinelist set Stock='" +Integer.parseInt(NumberField.getText())+x
                +"'where Barcode='"+ BarcodeField.getText()+"'";
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                preparedStmt.executeUpdate();


                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done!!!");


                con.close();

            }catch(Exception e) { System.out.print(e);}
        }

});
```

...

Comment: Just read the error message. Your SQL query contains `'10013''where`. That's incorrect SQL. Why do you concatenate `x` to the middle of your update query? And even most importantly, why don't you use prepared statements? Do you want any attacker to do anything to your database through SQL injection? If not, use prepared statements.

Comment: Which prepared statements? We are new at MySQL

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Can you give us an example code? We cannot understand

Comment: The link I posted has examples of code, with explanations. Read it, carefully. read it again if necessary. Some things take more than 5 minutes to grasp.

Comment: Try to dump SQL query in console after values are concatenated. Then try to run it directly in SQL editors. This will help narrow down the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query

```
 '" +Integer.parseInt(NumberField.getText())+ x +"'where
```

Put  +"`'`where query behind `x` like this

```
 '" +Integer.parseInt(NumberField.getText())+"'"+ x +" where
```

and also put spaces for clean query.

Comment: N.B. Please note that Maria DB and MySQL not same.

Answer (score 1):

String x = "Select Stock from medicinelist where Barcode='" + BarcodeField.getText()+"'";

And

String sql = "Update medicinelist set Stock='" +Integer.parseInt(NumberField.getText())+x
                +"'where Barcode='"+ BarcodeField.getText()+"'";

So string sql becomes

String sql = "Update medicinelist set Stock='" +Integer.parseInt(NumberField.getText())+"Select Stock from medicinelist where Barcode='" + BarcodeField.getText()+"'"+"'where Barcode='"+ BarcodeField.getText()+"'";

And so is the error :)

Collect the "string x" query output in a resultset and use it in "string sql".

Answer (score 0):

```
      +"'where Barcode='"+ BarcodeField.getText()+"'";
```

There is no space between single quote and **where**. Provide it and run again.